# How to update a python program while it is running

Tags: python

If a program is running, is there any way to update it as it runs and have the program respond? Python.

I have a program that changes its own code. It takes user input and adds it to a list in the program itself. After that, it is possible to examine all of the elements in the list. However, I cannot get it to show newly added elements to the list in the response. Is there even any way to do this, like calling a function but re-calling the whole program(with updates)?

```
L = [1, 2, 3]
I = input("Input a number to add to the set")
K = []
global K
with open(__file__, 'r') as f:
    S = f.read().split('\n')  #split the file into lines, add them to a list
    V = S[0].split(' = ')[-1]  #take the first line(the list L), take the part after the = sign
    M = 1
    while V[M] != ']':  #this while loop is just a way to access the stuff inside the square brackets without the square brackets
        K.append(V[M])
        M += 1
    N = 'L = [{}, {}]'.format("".join(K), int(I))  #creates the new line to sub in for the first line in the program
    with open(__file__, 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join([N] + S[1:]))  #subs it in
print(L)  #to return the list, without the added input. Can it return the list with I added?
```

I don't know if there is any way to solve this, as it could well be that a program, once running starts, cannot run from a different file(or different version of a file). However, if there is a way, I would love to hear it!

Comment: Why don't you save the data in another file, possibly in JSON or pickle format, instead of modifying the Python code?

Comment: One of basic principles of safe application design is to properly seperate data and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use better variable names.

Since you are using a file to write and read to, remember that once read, it's read into memory. If you want to modify the file and read the new data, you'll need to close the file and open it again to get the new data.

You'll also want to double check the context of that nested file read you are doing. Is it referring to the same file? Or are they two different files?